# asp.net InnerHtml text with link

Tags: asp.net, twitter

I am dynamically adding Html to a server-side DIV this way:

```
innerHtml = innerHtml + string.Format(@"<div><span>{0}</span><br/>{1}</div><br/>", dr["Date"], dr["State"]);
```

That's fine, problem is that Title column has normal text mixed with link ( it is the twitter state field), but the links are not rendered as hyperlink but as normal text and the user cannot click the links.

How do I address this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does `dr["State"]` contains? And is `dr` a DataRow? If Yes, why don't you use some kind of databinding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your Title column? Please add your code for the same.

If your link is dr["state"] your code will look like this.

```
innerHtml = innerHtml + string.Format(@"<div><span>{0}</span><br/><a href='{1}'>Link Name</a></div><br/>", dr["Date"], dr["State"]);
```

In short add the anchor tag (`<a href='Your link'>Link Name</a>`) in your string.

Comment: Hi Azhar, the content of the status column can be like this:
"Impuesto a la exportación permitiría subsidiar a multinacionales http://t.co/pblJo8rd #Economía"
Notice the link at the end of the string, that link is not rendered as a link, but as normal text.
Thanks

Comment: Impuesto a la exportación permitiría subsidiar a multinacionales http://t.co/pblJo8rd #Economía

Comment: You have to append the link in your string that I had mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, i just split the string and replace the link part with an anchor, it did it
Thanks